# Matlab, Same Data yields different plot

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

```
s=linspace(-3,3);

x=cosh(s);
y=sinh(s);

plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(-x,y)
%until here good plots
close all
x=[x,-x];
y=[y,y];
plot(x,y)
%above plot adds a line
```

Basically when i stack up my matrixes to plot them in one, Matlab adds a line for some reason.

Comment: The line is just there to connect the two parts of your graph, as you asked MATLAB to. If you don't want it, I'd suggest you to plot the two parts separately :
`x=[x.',-x.'];`
`y=[y.',y.'];`
`plot(x,y)`

Comment: @BillBokeey you should add that as an answer

Comment: Oh well, the day I'll post an answer on a question you've already answered has not come yet @Dan ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `plot` connects all your points with a linearly interpolated line. Since `sinh(y(end))` is not equal to `sinh(y(1))` and these two points are adjacent in your `y2 = [y,y]` when you plot `y2` MATLAB will linearly interpolate between those two points and hence the line.

If you don't want the line but you want to plot this as a single series, try adding `NaN` where you want the gap i.e.

```
x2 = [x, NaN, -x];
y2 = [y, NaN, y];
plot(x2,y2)
```